# How to get the context menu in Visual Studio Publish App_Data and Replace App_Data from server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, visual-studio-2013, orchardcms

Ok as the title suggests, I can't get these contextmenu's into my IDE. I've looked , searched and installed almost everything.

The weird part is I got these contextmenu's working on both my workpc and my laptop, however for some reason I can't get these to appear on my normal pc. Does anyone know where I need put a checkmark or what I need to install to get this to work ( I already installed a lot of Azure packages from WebMatrix but so far it has all failed.
[context menu Publish App_Data & Replace App_Data from server](http://postimg.org/image/k6vd6v7lv/)

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hello Bertrand , I just want to be able to get my current production db from Azure and these options in the context menu enable me to do that quickly.

Comment: Why `App_Data`? Do you mean that you're deploying SqlCE in production?

Comment: That's correct Bertrand.

Comment: You most definitely shouldn't use SqlCE in production. You can be pretty certain that it'll cause trouble. You may want to check out those videos. They are old, but should still be relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YM35lnaI1sA https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5XCKylOdbI

Comment: thanks Bertrand , I'm going to implement these.